# linq returning query with a list of ids

Tags: c#, linq, filter, where-clause, contains

I'm doing a filter and I need all the values that has for example (rock = id 3 and jazz = id 6)

How can I do that in LINQ ?

I'm doing this but this gives first the one with rock and the with jazz....

```
private IQueryable<Performance>addGenreFilterToPerformanceQuery(IQueryable<Performance> query, List<int> genreFilters)
{
    if (genreFilters != null)
    {
        foreach (var genreFilter in genreFilters)
        {
            return query.Where(p => p.Artist.Genres.Any(g => genreFilters.Contains(g.Id)));
        }
    }
    return query;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. It would really help if you'd show a short but *complete* example, including sample input and expected output. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` isn't really doing anything.  If you want the query to match *all* genre ids rather than any, use `All`, not `Any`:

```
return query.Where(p => p.Artist.Genres.All(g => genreFilters.Contains(g.Id)));
```

Comment: The code is definitely broken, but it's not entirely clear to me whether this is what's wanted - the question is horribly unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet you're possibly right.  The first line sounds like this is what's being asked, but I could be wrong!